# Trying to import MongoDB documents as separate types in elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

If there's anybody who can point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated :)

I'm able to import a collection from MongoDB to elasticsearch, with the following transform_file.js code:

```
t.Source("source", source, '/^categories$/').Save("sink", sink, "/.*/")
```

In elasticsearch (using appbase.io), the data is indexed with the MongoDB collection 'categories' being the only type, while all the MongoDB documents are elasticsearch documents.

However, I want each of the MongoDB documents to instead be their own elasticsearch type. So instead of 'categories' being the only type in elasticsearch, I want the types to be BMW and Audi. Ideally named category_bmw and category_audi.

I assume it's the code after '.Save' that has to be changed, but I'm not exactly sure what changes to make.

EDIT: I'm using elasticsearch version 5.

Answer (score 0):

Stick to a single `_type`. Multiple types per index are gradually being removed in Elasticsearch and you'll only have unnecessary upgrading pains further down the road if you do that.

Instead use a custom field for example `type` (no leading underscore) or whatever makes sense for you. You can then use a filter on that custom field and get the same behavior as with multiple types.

Without showing the original document in MongoDB I'm not sure if you need any additional transformations or not.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Here is the command I've been using with appbase.io abc, which includes the database:

.\abc import --transform_file="transform_file.js" --src_type=mongodb --src_uri="mongodb://readonly:VWX57gafg6CPeqgjMPyJf@ds227481.mlab.com:27481/user_database_bugtest" "https://[appbase.io Admin API Key]@scalr.api.appbase.io/[app name]"

Comment: Guess I can use the existing field categoryname, trying to figure out how to implement it.